# Including MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 to C# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using System.data.odbc with "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}" in the connection string. However, I have not realised there is MySQL connector installed on my PC so however I have not referenced it, it doesn work without it.
Now I need to distribute it embed in the app. I have downloaded MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 files, but with Add reference it says "The file is not accessible...make sure its valid COM.." etc.
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

[MySQL Connector/ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) is, as the name suggests, just an ODBC driver for connecting to MySQL. It's not specifically designed for .NET and you can't embed it in your .NET applications in any way. It will need separate installation on any machine where you need to use it.

[MySQL Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) is a fully managed ADO.NET provider for MySQL. It's tailor-made for .NET and doesn't require the installation of any other software. It's easy to reference and distribute in your .NET applications, you'll just need to use the `System.Data.MySqlClient` namespace and objects rather than `System.Data.Odbc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the .NET DLL, but not the driver itself.  You'll need to install MySQL Connector on every computer that runs your application.

Comment: Are you sure? What about MySQL connector .NET, when referenced, you can use its namespace

Comment: AFAIK the referenced DLL still requires a driver.  But I'm never 100% sure, if you find a way, I'd be very interested :)

Comment: I find it pretty limitating if users are forced to install another piece of software. What is the difference between MySQL ODBC Driver and .NET Connector?

Comment: I think the .NET Connector makes the ODBC driver easy to use from .NET programs

Comment: Maybe...it confuses me that with .NET you can reference that mysqldata.dll and use its namespaces.

Comment: Guys, can we keep the misinformation to a minimum? 1. The .NET MySql Connector is standalone - no mysterious "driver" is needed beyond it. 2. You don't have to "install" it - just reference it: drop it in your resource section and Assembly.Load it when the app starts.

Comment: @Frank Krueger: If that's true, you could copy the MySql.Data.dll with your program and it would run on any machine?  I'll test that, if it's true it'll save us a lot of work, as we've been deploying the Connector installation to a lot of machines.

Comment: @Andomar: It's true for Connector/Net, but *not* for Connector/ODBC, as I explained in my answer. MySql.Data.dll is part of Connector/Net but the question suggests that the OP is using Connector/ODBC in their application.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing u need is Mysql.Data.Dll
You don't need to install the complete connector, everything u need is in there.
That also counts for the end user, they also only need the dll